# Refactor nested loops into a single LINQ Query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to refactor this into a query:

```
 while (IsRunning)
 {

 ...

 //specialPoint is a string
 foreach (PointTypeItem pointTypeItem in PointTypeItemCollection)
    {
        foreach (PointItem pointItem in pointTypeItem.PointItemCollection)
        {
            //Replace the point name with point ID
            if (specialPoint.Contains(pointItem.PointName))
            {
                replacedCode += s.Replace(specialPoint , pointItem.ID);
                //I want to go back to the beginning point of while (IsRunning) from here
                //Simply putting continue; here won't work
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

I basically want to turn this into a LINQ query but I'm stuck writing one. Actually, I'm not even sure if I'm taking this the right direction.

```
var results = from pointTypeItem in ddcItem.PointTypeItemCollection
              where pointTypeItem.PointItemCollection.Any(pointItem => pointName.Contains(pointItem.PointName))
              select //What do I select?
```

Comment: Anyway you stil would iterate through each item, so what's the purpose of this refactoring?

Comment: What's `s` and what's `replacedCode`? Can you provide a simply example and a desired result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var results = from pointTypeItem in ddcItem.PointTypeItemCollection
              from pointItem in pointTypeItem.PointItemCollection
              where specialPoint.Contains(pointItem.PointName)
              select pointItem.ID;
```

gets an `IEnumerable<the type of pointItem.ID>`.

Comment: Sick, I never knew you could nest the from clause inside! Thanks. Very insightful

Comment: @l46kok That's not actually a nested query.  It will be translated into a single call to `SelectMany` rather than executing a query for each query.

Comment: @Richard Based on the comments in the code in the OP, he'll need a `First` call at the end of the query.

Comment: @Servy Maybe, the contents of the `if` doesn't make sense as it stands: unclear what `s` is. The comments would suggest making the replacement in `specialPoint` (`specialPoint.Replace(pointItem, pointItem.ID)`) but then the `if` wouldn't be needed (if the name isn't present the replacement would be a no-op).

Answer (score 2):

You could do this using the SelectMany() extension method:

```
 PointTypeItemCollection.SelectMany(pointCollection => pointCollection.PointItemCollection)
                .Where(pointItem => pointItem.PointName.Contains(specialPoint))
                .Select(pointItem => pointItem.ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to test without having any values but what about something like this?

```
      replacedCode = string.Concat(
        this.PointTypeItemCollection.SelectMany(i => i.PointItemCollection)
        .Where(i => specialPoint.Contains(i.PointName))
        .Select(i => s.Replace(specialPoint, i.ID))
      );
```